# Something wrong with your Account Key

Tags: quickblox

I am getting error "Something wrong with your Account Key." even my account key is correct and I am using "QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(qbConfigs.getAccountKey());" in my application class.

Please help!!

Comment: Judging by what Google tells me, the error message should also state "please check it in quickblox admin panel", did you do this? Does the admin panel give you any information about the state of your account key?

Comment: Yes i have already checked it. It says to check whether the account key entered is correct or not. In my case it is correct.
And I am getting this error in my Enterprise package

Answer (score 0):

Af far as I know you can get that error if you indicate Account key of your Enterprise account, but your app still points to shared instance. 
Did you try contacting their support?